# AMD Radeon R7 450 card not detected

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, opencl

Ok so the official blender site says that if an amd card has gcn 1st gen or newer architecture, the amd card is compatible
[image]

And my card i.e. AMD Radeon R7 450 has GCN 1st Gen architecture as mentioned here
[image]

then also my Blender isnt recognising the card when i switch to open cl. That is a whole 4gb og GPU memory wasted
Can anybody pls guide me as i have tried all available options
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your GPU fulfills the minimum requirements for *running* Blender 2.8x. However, it does not meet the requirements for *GPU rendering*.

Comment: if u are familiar with sheepit, it can use my gpu for rendring other peoples file using blender application. ow is it then sheepit is able to identify the gpu and render through it via blender but my native isnt able to identify it ?

Comment: I haven't checked, but it's likely because SheepIt uses multiple Blender versions and projects for Blender 2.79 are rendered with that specific version. The older version had lower requirements and allows GPU rendering on your hardware. BTW Blender 2.8x is able to identify it, but since it's below the minimum requirements for GPU rendering Blender doesn't list it.

Comment: see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware